# Right place for React Server side rendering API call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, reactive-programming, server-side-rendering

We're using ComponentWillMount() life cycle for API calls in react 15 for server side rendering. Now, we going to migrating our application to react 16.8 which is ideal place to call API action in server side rendering?

Comment: What's API call? Is it asynchronous request to HTTP API? It's not supported in SSR.

Comment: Yes, it is react saga asynchronous API call

Comment: How did this work with React 15? You likely don't need to do this at all because async side effects won't be taken into account on server side. They go to componentDidMount, which is executed only on client side.

Comment: @Pradeepdevendran It would be helpful if you post the answer.

Comment: We moved our api calls under constructors for class components and used useeffect(()=>{},[]) for function based components.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount() should be the one you're looking for.

PFB link to help you more :[where should i place my api call](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-lifecycle-methods/)